# Left join of tables getting so many records. php pdo mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
"SELECT *,t1.pin AS table1.1pin"
        . ",t3.pin AS table2.1pin"
        . ",t6.pin AS table3.1pin"
        . ",t9.pin AS table4.1pin"
        . ",t2.tin AS table1.1tin"
        . ",t2.first_name AS table1.1firstname"
        . ",t2.last_name AS table1.1lastname"
        . ",t2.middle_name AS table1.1middlename"
        . ",t2.suffix AS table1.1suffix"
        . ",t5.tin AS table2.1tin"
        . ",t5.first_name AS table2.1firstname"
        . ",t5.last_name AS table2.1lastname"
        . ",t5.middle_name AS table2.1middlename"
        . ",t5.suffix AS table2.1suffix"
        . ",t8.tin AS table3.1tin"
        . ",t8.first_name AS table3.1firstname"
        . ",t8.last_name AS table3.1lastname"
        . ",t8.middle_name AS table3.1middlename"
        . ",t8.suffix AS table3.1suffix"
        . ",t10.tin AS table4.1tin"
        . ",t10.first_name AS table4.1firstname"
        . ",t10.last_name AS table4.1lastname"
        . ",t10.middle_name AS table4.1middlename"
        . ",t10.suffix AS table4.1suffix"
        . ",t1.effectivity_qtr AS table1qtr"
        . ",t1.effectivity_year AS table1year"
        . ",t4.effectivity_qtr AS table2qtr"
        . ",t4.effectivity_year AS table2year"
        . ",t7.effectivity_qtr AS table3qtr"
        . ",t7.effectivity_year AS table3year"
        . ",t9.effectivity_qtr AS table4qtr"
        . ",t9.effectivity_year AS table4year"
        . " FROM "
        . "table1 AS t1 "
        . "LEFT JOIN table1.1 AS t2 ON t1.pin = t2.pin AND t1.status = t2.status "
        . "LEFT JOIN table2 AS t3 ON t1.pin= t3.table2_pin AND t1.status = t3.status "
        . "LEFT JOIN table2.1 AS t4 ON t3.pin = t4.pin AND t3.status = t4.status "
        . "LEFT JOIN table2.2 AS t5 ON t3.pin = t5.pin AND t3.status = t5.status "
        . "LEFT JOIN table3 AS t6 ON t1.pin = t6.table3_pin AND t1.status = t6.status "
        . "LEFT JOIN table3.1 AS t7 ON t6.pin = t7.pin AND t6.status = t7.status "
        . "LEFT JOIN table3.2 AS t8 ON t6.pin = t8.pin AND t6.status = t8.status "
        . "LEFT JOIN table4 AS t9 ON t1.pin = t9.pin AND t1.status = t9.status "
        . "LEFT JOIN table4.1 AS t10 ON t1.pin = t10.pin AND t1.status = t10.status "
        . "WHERE "
        . "t1.pin LIKE '%$pin%' AND t1.status = 'Active' ";
```

I have left join of 10 tables where 4 of them has 3 row each and the rest have only one row. I want to get all the rows in the 10 tables so I used `LEFT JOIN` incase one of the tables has no record there will be something to return. Currently my tables consist of 1 row each except 4 tables which have 3 rows each so I am expecting to get 12 rows in total. But when i echo `rowCount()` i am getting `81 rows` its `more like 3 X 3 X 3 X 3`.

1. Why is this happening.
2. How would I make the correct select query in order or get the 12 desired rows.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

`FYI`

Also tried union but i think it is not possible in my case I only need record if they exist as I know union will add null values if there are empty tables.

`ADDITION INFO`

1. t1.pin exists in t1.1 as pin
2. t1.pin exists in t2 as table2_pin (t2 has column pin which then exist in t2.1)
3. t2.pin exists in t2.1 as pin
4. t2.pin exists in t2.2 as pin
5. t1.pin exixsts in t3 as table3_pin (t3 has column pin which then exist in t3.1)
6. t3.pin exists in t3.1 as pin
7. t3.pin exists in t3.2 as pin
8. t1.pin exists in t4 as pin
9. t1.pin exists in t4.1 as pin

[DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f569f/8)

[UPDATED DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f569f/30)

`UPDATE`
What i want to achieve is get all data from table that will satisfy the where clause in this sample i put in `like 1`. In short i want to get all data in tables.

```
pin                          effectivity_qtr    effectivity_year    status      tin             last_name   first_name  middle_name suffix      
015-08-0011-000-01           1st                2013                Active      342-432-423-000 Smith       John        James       Jr  
015-08-0011-000-01           1st                2014                Active      342-432-423-000 Smith       John        James       Jr  
015-08-0011-000-01           1st                2015                Active      342-432-423-000 Smith       John        James       Jr  
015-08-0011-000-01-1001      1st                2013                Active      342-432-423-000 Smith       John        James       Jr  
015-08-0011-000-01-1001      1st                2014                Active      342-432-423-000 Smith       John        James       Jr  
015-08-0011-000-01-1001      1st                2015                Active      342-432-423-000 Smith       John        James       Jr  
015-08-0011-000-01-2001      1st                2013                Active      342-432-423-000 Smith       John        James       Jr  
015-08-0011-000-01-2001      1st                2014                Active      342-432-423-000 Smith       John        James       Jr  
015-08-0011-000-01-2001      1st                2015                Active      342-432-423-000 Smith       John        James       Jr  
015-08-0011-000-01           1st                2013                Active      342-432-423-000 Smith       John        James       Jr  
015-08-0011-000-01           1st                2014                Active      342-432-423-000 Smith       John        James       Jr  
015-08-0011-000-01           1st                2015                Active      342-432-423-000 Smith       John        James       Jr
```

`UPDATED EXPECTED OUTPUT`

```
sysid   pin effectivity_qtr effectivity_year    status  sys_id  tin pin last_name   first_name  middle_name suffix  status  sys_id  pin table2_pin  status  sysid   pin effectivity_qtr effectivity_year    status  sys_id  tin pin last_name   first_name  middle_name suffix  status  sys_id  pin table3_pin  status  sys_id  pin status  effectivity_qtr effectivity_year    sys_id  tin pin last_name   first_name  middle_name suffix  status  sys_id  pin status  effectivity_qtr effectivity_year    sys_id  tin pin last_name   first_name  suffix  middle_name status  pin pin pin pin tin first_name  last_name   middle_name suffix  tin first_name  last_name   middle_name suffix  tin first_name  last_name   middle_name suffix  tin first_name  last_name   middle_name suffix  effectivity_qtr effectivity_year    effectivity_qtr effectivity_year    effectivity_qtr effectivity_year    effectivity_qtr effectivity_year
1   015-08-0011-000-01  1st 2013    Active  1   342-432-423-000 015-08-0011-000-01  Smith   John    James   Jr  Active  1   015-08-0011-000-01-1001 015-08-0011-000-01  Active  1   015-08-0011-000-01-1001 1st 2013    Active  1   342-432-423-000 015-08-0011-000-01-1001 Smith   John    James   Jr  Active  1   015-08-0011-000-01-2001 015-08-0011-000-01  Active  1   015-08-0011-000-01-2001 Active  1st 2013    1   342-432-423-000 015-08-0011-000-01-2001 Smith   John    James   Jr  Active  1   015-08-0011-000-01  Active  1st 2013    1   342-432-423-000 015-08-0011-000-01  Smith   John    Jr  James   Active  015-08-0011-000-01  015-08-0011-000-01-1001 015-08-0011-000-01-2001 015-08-0011-000-01  342-432-423-000 John    Smith   James   Jr  342-432-423-000 John    Smith   James   Jr  342-432-423-000 John    Smith   James   Jr  342-432-423-000 John    Smith   James   Jr  1st 2013    1st 2013    1st 2013    1st 2013
2   015-08-0011-000-01  1st 2014    Active  1   342-432-423-000 015-08-0011-000-01  Smith   John    James   Jr  Active  1   015-08-0011-000-01-1001 015-08-0011-000-01  Active  1   015-08-0011-000-01-1001 1st 2014    Active  1   342-432-423-000 015-08-0011-000-01-1001 Smith   John    James   Jr  Active  1   015-08-0011-000-01-2001 015-08-0011-000-01  Active  1   015-08-0011-000-01-2001 Active  1st 2014    1   342-432-423-000 015-08-0011-000-01-2001 Smith   John    James   Jr  Active  1   015-08-0011-000-01  Active  1st 2014    1   342-432-423-000 015-08-0011-000-01  Smith   John    Jr  James   Active  015-08-0011-000-01  015-08-0011-000-01-1001 015-08-0011-000-01-2001 015-08-0011-000-01  342-432-423-000 John    Smith   James   Jr  342-432-423-000 John    Smith   James   Jr  342-432-423-000 John    Smith   James   Jr  342-432-423-000 John    Smith   James   Jr  1st 2014    1st 2014    1st 2014    1st 2014
3   015-08-0011-000-01  1st 2015    Active  1   342-432-423-000 015-08-0011-000-01  Smith   John    James   Jr  Active  1   015-08-0011-000-01-1001 015-08-0011-000-01  Active  1   015-08-0011-000-01-1001 1st 2015    Active  1   342-432-423-000 015-08-0011-000-01-1001 Smith   John    James   Jr  Active  1   015-08-0011-000-01-2001 015-08-0011-000-01  Active  1   015-08-0011-000-01-2001 Active  1st 2015    1   342-432-423-000 015-08-0011-000-01-2001 Smith   John    James   Jr  Active  1   015-08-0011-000-01  Active  1st 2015    1   342-432-423-000 015-08-0011-000-01  Smith   John    Jr  James   Active  015-08-0011-000-01  015-08-0011-000-01-1001 015-08-0011-000-01-2001 015-08-0011-000-01  342-432-423-000 John    Smith   James   Jr  342-432-423-000 John    Smith   James   Jr  342-432-423-000 John    Smith   James   Jr  342-432-423-000 John    Smith   James   Jr  1st 2015    1st 2015    1st 2015    1st 2015
 Record Count: 3; Execution Time: 8ms View Execution Plan  link
Did this query solve the problem? If so, consider donating $5 to help make sure SQL Fiddle will be here next time you need help with a database problem. Thanks!
SQL Sentry  CollectServer.info - Easy Server Health Monitoring
```

The first expected output i posted must have made confusion so i decided to post another one. THis is straight from sqlfiddle i just adjusted few values which is not correct. I want to get all data per year. I hope this is now clear.

I am open to any other select query as long as i can get all data per year. Things to consider are pin can be multiple in some tables some tables can be empty.

Comment: use DISTINCT keyword after SELECT............

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT t1.pin AS` i did like this i removed `*` i still get 81 rows

Comment: if you create a sqlfiddle then i can help you.

Comment: where can i an sqlfiddle sorry i havent done that can you post a link?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: give me time to create the fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91544/discussion-between-brownman-revival-and-zafar-malik).

Comment: Hi i am getting Request content too large (>8000) so i suppose i will just use half of the tables and random data please bear with me

Comment: please check the fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f569f/8

Comment: updated demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f569f/10

Answer (score 0):

Joins create a cross product of the tables. In your case, there are multiple rows with the same value of `pin`, so the join works like this:

```
table1                          table2_                             table3__                  
                                                                                              
                                1. 015-08-0011-000-01-1001 +------> 1. 015-08-0011-000-01-1001
1. 015-08-0011-000-01-1001 +--> 2. 015|08|0011|000|01|1001+-----+   2. 015|08|0011|000|01|1001
                                3. 015-08-0011-000-01-1001 +-+  |   3. 015-08-0011-000-01-1001
                                                             |  |                             
                                1. 015-08-0011-000-01-1001   |  |   1. 015-08-0011-000-01-1001
2. 015-08-0011-000-01-1001 +--> 2. 015|08|0011|000|01|1001   |  +-> 2. 015|08|0011|000|01|1001
                                3. 015-08-0011-000-01-1001   |      3. 015-08-0011-000-01-1001
                                                             |                                
                                1. 015-08-0011-000-01-1001   |      1. 015-08-0011-000-01-1001
3. 015-08-0011-000-01-1001 +--> 2. 015|08|0011|000|01|1001   +----> 2. 015|08|0011|000|01|1001
                                3. 015-08-0011-000-01-1001          3. 015-08-0011-000-01-1001
                                                                                              
                                                                                              
                                                                                              
                                                                          ...
```

To show exactly one row per entry in `table1`, add `GROUP BY t1.sysid` at the end of the query.

Comment: SIr there might be a possibility that there will be more that one entry per one entry in table1 is there another way?

Comment: Use a unique identifier as foreign key instead of the pin?

Comment: sir pin is unique in each table no other row will have the pin. the pin work as the foreign key.

Comment: I did. Please tell me how the pin (second column) is unique: `(1, '015-08-0011-000-01', '1st', '2013', 'Active'),
(2, '015-08-0011-000-01', '1st', '2014', 'Active'),
(3, '015-08-0011-000-01', '1st', '2015', 'Active');`

Comment: Im sorry totally forgot that table.also in the table where there is name there can also be multiple pin. My question is why didnt it work when i tried it using sysid(this one is unique because it is auto increment) i get not complete year i only get 2013 for other tables only table1 has complete year

Comment: that is the only problem i have if i add group by sys id. the year in other tables are all 2013 the year 2014 and 2015 is not shown any idea on that?

Comment: I don't understand what result you expect. If you join by sysid instead of pin, you don't need to group by sysid anymore and will get three result rows (with all years).

Comment: if i join by sysid it not always the same for example there might be instance that the table4 will be empty that is why i used LEFT JOIN so that i can get non empty response. Can you suggest other select query for this i just want to get all data from all tables.where their pin number is like 1 which in this case all of them has 1

Comment: please update your question with the *desired result*

Comment: please check the updated question with the desired output